# Plz help me continuous about Mean Value Theorem

Tags: derivatives

> $|\sinh x|\geq|x|, \forall  x \in \mathbb{R}$

$$ f(x) = \sinh x  $$

$$f'(c)= \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} $$

$$\cosh (c)= \frac{\sinh b-\sinh a}{b-a}  $$

what can I do this continuous?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is asking? Can you elaborate and add your thinking to the question please?

Comment: I dont know a and b to define what will be

Comment: What is your actual question? Can you edit your post to explain this, and show what you've done to try and get an answer?

Answer (score 1):

From $$\cosh c=\frac{\sinh b-\sinh a}{b-a}$$

Let $b=x$ and $a=0$, then we have $$\cosh c=\frac{\sinh x-\sinh 0}{x-0}$$

That is $$|\frac{\sinh x}{x}| = |\cosh c| \ge 1$$

Cross multiply to get $$|\sinh x|\ge |x|$$

Comment: sorry,sir why a=0 and b=x or bound of sinh between -infinity and infinity , and pick a=0 b=x for all x Right?

Comment: While the equality $\cosh c=\frac{\sinh b-\sinh a}{b-a}$ holds for all $a,b,c$ we want to use it so we can prove$ |\sinh x|\ge |x|$ therefore we choose what provides us with a solution.